# Why do the vertical forces exerted on each end of the bridge by its supports have different values?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

Imagine that a person is walking across a uniform level bridge and stops three-fourths of the way from one end.

Why do the vertical forces exerted on each end of the bridge by its supports have different values? Why doesn't the bridge exert the same force on them? I understand that the person isn't standing at the center of the bridge, but why does that have to result in the imbalance of the forces on the bridge (i.e. why can't the bridge average out the forces on it)?

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the sum of the moments at the reactions.

There are two requirements for the bridge to be in equilibrium. The sum of the forces and the sum of the moments have to be zero.

$$\sum \vec F=0$$
$$\sum \vec M=0$$

Assuming the only load on the bridge (ignoring the weight of the bridge) is the person walking across, then the sum of the reactions at the supports will equal the weight of the person. But as the person walks across the bridge the sum of the moments about the supports changes and this results in the reactions at the supports changing.

See the free body diagram of the bridge below, which for simplicity neglects the weight of the bridge (which would add a constant value to each reaction if the bridge is uniform). As you can see from the equations, if x = 0, all the weight of the person is supported by the support at A. If x = L (the length of the bridge), it is all supported by the support at B. If the person is midway, the reactions are equal.

Hope this helps.

[image]